# IExcel not comparing dates properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I have a table with two dates in the following format:

- C1  `Sep 21, 2017 10:22 AM`
- C2 `Sep 28, 2017 10:09 AM`

If I run the following if statement against them...

`=IF(M4<L4, "Fail", "Pass")`

...then the formula returns `Pass`. However if the two dates are in different months the formula fails.

For example,

- C1 `[Sep 26, 2017 03:14 PM]`
- C2 `[Oct 2, 2017 03:39 PM]`
- returns `Fail`.

The value of C1 is lower than C2 yet the formula still fails.

It doesn't make a difference to the return value if the cell is formatted as text or date. and the `=DateValue()` function will not work, it returns `#VALUE`

Any Ideas?

Comment: essentially i am looking to compare the values of each column. c1 is the time something was fixed and c2 is the time it is required to be fixed by. If the time it was fixed is after the due time then the formula needs to respond as failed otherwise its a pass

Comment: I think your last point that `DateValue` doesn't work is the problem, if Excel can't parse the text into what it recognizes as date, then it will be likely doing text comparisons, and hence "O" is < "S".   Try formatting the data so that DateValue parses.

Comment: @SalemTheCat so I assume right that C1 stands for Column 1 and C2 stands for column 2? So the cells you are referring to are actually M4 and L4, right?

Comment: @SalemTheCat you should not only write you're specifications into the comment but also edit you're question so it will be easier to read. I did it for you this time.

Comment: @SalemTheCat I updated my answer, it should work now, at least it works in my excel version.

Answer (score 2):

In you're formula you are not comparing C1 and C2 but M4 and L4. If you want to compare C1 and C2 directly you should use those values in you're formula as well.

This formula, for example

```
=IF(C1<C2, "Fail", "Pass")
```

will show "Fail" if the date/time in cell C1 is smaller then the Date in cell C2. If the date in C1 is larger or equal it will show "Pass". The cells C1 and C2 should be formatted as date, not as text. In both cells it has to be a date or user defined format (which uses the time and date variables excel offers, like YYYY, MMM, DD etc.). If you use text-format the "if-clause" won't compare time/date but strings, which gives you you're "funny" results!

The function DateValue() only works on cells with text-format and only within a certain scope, it does not work with you're notation. It works with `31.07.2018 20:36` but does not work with `Jul 31, 2018 08:36 PM`.

Answer (score 2):

If statements works in the following way:

```
=IF( Logical Test, Value if test is TRUE, value if test is FALSE)
```

So you may want to use:

```
=IF(C2<C1,"Pass",Fail")
```

I did not 100% understand your question, so you may need to swap `<` for `>`

Logical operators you can use:

- `>` , Greater Than
- `<` Less Than
- `=` Equals
- `<=` Less Than or equal to
- `>=` greater than or equal to
- `<>` does not equal

Answer (score 0):

`cjb110` in 99.999% certainly right in his comment.

The reason it doesn't matter if you format as a date or as outright text is because, to Excel, it is outright text and looks identical to it either way. Also as pointed out, Excel, in the situation, will actually do an alphabetical comparison, and "S" is "greater than" "O" as it appears later in the alphabet. The "successful" comparison isn't successful. It LOOKS successful, but is only alphabetically correct, not numerically or date-ly correct (the "1" in "Sep 21" is "less than" the "8" in "Sep 28" alphabetically, so it seems to succeed, but in fact doesn't do anything of the sort).

To accomplish your task, you need to pull out the parts that matter and feed them into a function that generates a date and/or time. For instance, for the data in the "Sep 21, 2017 10:22AM" line you can find the date with something like the following:

```
=DATEVALUE(L4)
```

Your date string is close enough for Excel to make it out so it's as simple as that. Dates are stored in Excel as the number of days from a starting point, the usual one being 1/1/1900 and times are stored as a decimal number between 0 and just less than 1. For this date, those are 42999 and .431944444 so the date and time value really stored is 42999.431944444.

You do not have to actually change the data in your worksheet. You just need to change it to date/time in your formula. So, for L4, the date and time can be found with:

```
=DATEVALUE(L4) + TIMEVALUE(L4)
```

and since you can do the same for the later date/time, you could compare the data AS dates and times with something like the following:

```
=( =DATEVALUE(M4) + TIMEVALUE(M4) ) - ( DATEVALUE(L4) + TIMEVALUE(L4) )
```

which preserves the logic of what you're doing so when you look back on it in a year, it will be easy to realize what you did.

Not sure how `Albin` experienced `DATEVALUE()` failing to work on your strings as they worked without the least effort for me. I believe I must chalk it down to differences in Excel version with the function apparently being better at things nowadays.

But that may not be true, and someone reading this who DOES see it fail on a string like that might find it is down to Windows settings one has chosen. My settings may include formatting a date/time like yours or close to it. After all, no matter what Excel functions will do with something they recognize as a date/time, they do have to recognize it as such first and Excel looks to Windows to do that recognizing. Seems a little bizarre, but if one has different enough Windows settings, then one's version of Windows may fail to see these strings as dates/times and so Excel never knows they are. Then `DATEVALUE()`, say, would see those strings the same as it sees a string like `SJFHHYUR98234..||mm,*jjds`... not a date, not a time, just some random string. So something to investigate perhaps, if one experiences that.

Or one could accept it and move on to the faster business of just tearing the string apart and building a string Excel WILL recognize, then passing it to `DATEVALUE()` or `DATE()` and being done with the whole shebang. Not everyone is interested in "Excel At the Edges"...